# SQL Server - Sum Until Threshold Reached

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with shift worked information for each employee.  The main table (called "shift_worked") is structured like the following:

```
id    employee_id  period    day   hours
1     154          6         5     4.5
2     156          7         12    7.25
3     154          7         6     8
4     154          7         7     6.75
5     142          7         7     5.5
6     156          8         12    7.1
```

I need to determine the period and day in which each employee hit a threshold of working 500 hours... or of course be able to determine who has not yet reached this threshold.

I am trying to look at recursive queries to handle this, but I am just not able to work it out.

***** EDIT *****
I only provided it in the comments, but the db is SQL Server 2008 - sadly none of the nice 2012 commands will work.

Comment: What query do you have so far?

Comment: Allow me to clarify... by "trying to look at recursive queries", I mean I am nowhere near having anything that makes sense.  I can post gibberish, if that would help.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense... but this is actually a very large table and the calculation takes a very long time.  Is it possible to speed things up by no longer working out a running total once the threshold is reached?

Comment: You said you're looking at recursive queries. Maybe you could post a link to an example you're trying to apply as a point of reference.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Yeah... sadly it's 2008 (I know... not my choice).

Answer (score 0):

Our Table looks like this, from what I understand:

```
CREATE TABLE #data (id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
 employee_id  INT ,
 period    INT ,
 [day] INT,
 [hours] DECIMAL (8,3))
```

Making data:

```
DECLARE @seed INT = 0, 
    @max INT = 10000,
    @employee INT

WHILE @seed < @max
BEGIN
    SET @employee =100 + RAND()*40 

    INSERT INTO #data
            ( employee_id, period, day, hours)
    VALUES  ( @employee, -- employee_id - int
              1 + RAND() * 26, -- period - int
              1 + RAND() * 14, -- day - int
              4 + RAND() * 8  )

    SET @seed = @seed + 1
END
```

Used `Cross Apply` to Calculate current Total Hours for each Day+Period combination (assuming those are sequential).

```
SELECT da.employee_id, 
 MIN(da.period) AS [Period],
 -- Because getting min day gets the lowest day number of all periods
 MIN(da.period * 1000 + da.day) % 1000  AS [Day]

FROM #data da
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT d.employee_id, SUM(d.hours) AS [Hours]
    FROM #data d
    WHERE d.employee_id = da.employee_id    
    --Total number of days since period 1 day 1
    AND d.day + d.period * 14  < da.day + da.period  * 14 
    GROUP BY d.employee_id) total 

WHERE total.Hours > 500
GROUP BY da.employee_id
ORDER BY da.employee_id
```

Even with the new computed where clause the query takes 1 second to run against the 10k records I generate. You may be able to gain performance by indexing employee/day/period... I'd run analyzer to figure that part out.

Comment: First off, thank you for showing me the CROSS APPLY - very useful!  Unfortunately, it is not working out.  :(  It is giving me seemingly random results.  For one person I checked, it pulled out the pay period in which they reached over 800 hours instead of 500, and for another it gave me the most recent period where they had over 2000 hours worked...

Comment: @Steven. What is "period " and what is "day"? How do those things work together?

Comment: A "period" is a two-week pay period.  A day is numbered 1-14 and represents which day of the pay period the person worked.  Another table has the period number along with the period's start date.

Comment: I'm going to adjust the data generation and SQL to match those.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you seem to be looking for a cumulative total. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx.
Example using Max's very useful generator :-
declare @data table (employee_id int,period int,day int,hours int)

```
DECLARE @seed INT = 0
WHILE @seed < 10000
begin
    INSERT INTO @data
            ( employee_id, period, day, hours )
    VALUES  ( 100 + RAND()*40 , -- employee_id - int
              1 + RAND() * 8, -- period - int
              1 + RAND() * 14, -- day - int
              4 + RAND() * 8 -- hours - decimal
              )

    SET @seed = @seed + 1
END

SELECT * FROM
(
select   employee_id,period,day, hours
         ,      CumulativeTotal
         , row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by  cumulativetotal) ROWNUMBER
from 
(
select   employee_id,period,day, hours
        ,SUM(hours) OVER (partition by employee_id
         ORDER BY period,day 
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeTotal
from @data
--where employee_id = 100 
) s
where cumulativetotal >= 500
) T
WHERE T.ROWNUMBER = 1
order by T.employee_id ,T.period,T.day

/*Prove it by dropping into excel and adding a column in excel to confirm cumulative total*/
select employee_id ,period,day,hours
        ,SUM(hours) OVER (partition by employee_id
         ORDER BY period,day 
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeTotal
from @data
where   employee_id = 101
order   by  employee_id,period,day
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have at least SQL server 2012, then windowing functions are your best bet.

```
with IsThresholdReached (employee_id, period, day, threshold_reached) 
as (
    select employee_id, period, day,
           case when 
              sum(hours) over (partition by employee_id order by period, day rows unbounded preceding) >= 500
           then 1 else 0 end
    from shift_worked
),

ThresholdFirstReached (employee_id, period, day, first_reached_period, first_reached_day)
as (
    select employee_id, period, day,
           first_value(period) over (partition by employee_id order by period, day rows unbounded preceding),
           first_value(day) over (partition by employee_id order by period, day rows unbounded preceding)
    from IsThresholdReached
    where threshold_reached = 1
)

select employee_id, period, day
from ThresholdFirstReached
where period = first_reached_period
and day = first_reached_day
```

To explain: first expression above calculates whether or not the threshold has been exceeded yet for a given employee on a given period and day by tracking a cumulative sum of their worked hours. The second expression determines the first period and day in which this has happened, and the final select picks the actual rows in which the period and day are equal to those values